# let d3.js scale automatically values on the x axis

Tags: d3.js

using d3.js i have too many labels on the x axis is there a way to reduce the number of values on the x axis  and let d3.js scale automatically and choose how many values to show up cause The chart I need to create can have anywhere from a few values to hundreds
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use D3.js's `d3.axis` and `d3.scale` functions to automatically scale and adjust the number of values shown on the x-axis based on the data. One common approach is to use `d3.scaleTime()` for time-based data or `d3.scaleLinear()` for numerical data and then apply `.ticks()` to control the number of ticks displayed. Additionally, you can use `.tickFormat()` to customize the format of the ticks displayed. This allows D3.js to intelligently choose the number of ticks based on the available space and the range of your data.